# Why is my object invisible in the game?

Tags: game-engine, objects

I'm testing my door and saw a problem. as you see on the image you see that my object is normal in edit mode/object mode

[image]

But when I press <kbd>P</kbd> a part of that object is invisible, how is this possible? Can someone help please

[image]

Comment: Pretty vague, could be an inverted normals problem, impossible to tell with such little info. Please edit your question and provide more information like screenshots and object settings

Comment: You should always tell what object you are missing (e.g. mark it in the image where it is present. It would help us to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to disable transparency on opaque objects.

[image]

This does not only speed up render. It avoids sorting conflicts (that is what I think happens in your case).

Comment: Could you please add some more details to your answer.  Maybe some details and possibly a screenshot of how to do that.

Comment: added screenshoot